# Oracle SQL Query to retrieve records where a value in a column equals the count of values in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:
Table A

**AId** |  **ImageCount**

1        | 1
 2        | 1
 3        | 2

Table B

**BId**  | **AForeignKey**

1| 1
2| 3
3| 3

I was able to get this query, which gives me a visual comparison of the values:

SELECT t1.AId, t1.ImageCount, COUNT(t2.AForeignKey) AS RecordsInB 
FROM A t1
LEFT JOIN B t2 ON tw.AForeignKey = t1.AId
GROUP BY t1.AId, t1.ImageCount

but I can't figure out how to eliminate those rows where the ImageCount doesn't equal the RecordsInB.  All I really care about it the AId column, but I'm displaying the other columns in the above query just so I can visually compare.

So the output should look like this:

**AId**

1
3

Or for visual comparison:

**AId**|**ImageCount**|**RecordsInB**

1| 1 | 1

3| 2 | 2

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Looks like I don't know how to do the tables, sorry.  I'll see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Select only the column that you want to display and add a `distinct` in from the column that you select. Would that bring the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you need to filter the result of your query to only keep the rows `having t1.imageCount = COUNT(t2.AForeignKey)`.

If so, simply add this condition to your query:

```
SELECT t1.AId, t1.ImageCount, COUNT(t2.AForeignKey) AS RecordsInB 
FROM tableA t1
LEFT JOIN tableB t2 ON t2.AForeignKey = t1.AId
GROUP BY t1.AId, t1.ImageCount
having t1.imageCount = COUNT(t2.AForeignKey)
```

Comment: wow!  Simply missing the "Having" piece.  I guess I'll need to learn more about that.  Thank you!